# VB.net extract variable value inside <span> tags?

Tags: html, regex, vb.net

I'm trying to extract a decimal value that may vary from inside HTML using VB.net.

As sort of a test, here is the code I'm using:

```
 Dim result As String = "<td class='fl'><label>Balance:</label></td><td nowrap class='fd'><span>$999,999.99</span></td></tr></table></td>"
 Dim RegexResult = Regex.Match(result, "^(\$|)([1-9]\d{0,2}(\,\d{3})*|([1-9]\d*))(\.\d{2})?$")
 Console.WriteLine(RegexResult)
```

FYI, I found that expression here:

In this example, the extracted result should be: `$999999.99`. This will then be modified to strip the dollar sign.

Regex result, when viewed in the Visual Studio console is `{}`. How do I modify the expression to account for the `<span>` tags?

Comment: And what happens if there are other numbers on the page that fit that format? Regex has its uses, but I don't believe it's best for your situation. There are plenty of html parsers out there that would get you that value much more cleanly...

Comment: As soohoonigan says, consider something else like the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) which is made for this exact purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if your regex would work now, don't use regex to parse dynamic HTML content.

Use an available HTML parser like `HtmlAgilityPack`, that's a much more reliable solution:

```
Dim html = "<td class='fl'><label>Balance:</label></td><td nowrap class='fd'><span>$999,999.99</span></td></tr></table></td>"
Dim doc As New HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument()
doc.LoadHtml(html)
Dim td = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[contains(@class,'fd')]")
Dim spanText = td.Descendants("span").First().InnerText
Dim balance As Decimal
Dim usCulture = New CultureInfo("en-us")
Dim valid = Decimal.TryParse(spanText, NumberStyles.Currency, usCulture, balance)
```

Comment: Looks good, but where do CultureInfo and NumberStyles come from?

Comment: @JeffreyOllendorf System.Globalization